# How to filter Xml data in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

How can I get the CfgGroup/DBID value(s) if my filter value agentDBIDs/DBID value = 103?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<ConfData>
  <CfgAgentGroup>
    <CfgGroup>
      <DBID value="109" />
      <tenantDBID value="1" />
      <name value="group1" />
      <contractDBID value="0" />
    </CfgGroup>
    <agentDBIDs>
      <DBID value="103" />
      <DBID value="994" />
    </agentDBIDs>
  </CfgAgentGroup>
  <CfgAgentGroup>
    <CfgGroup>
      <DBID value="110" />
      <tenantDBID value="1" />
      <name value="group2" />     
      <contractDBID value="0" />
    </CfgGroup>
    <agentDBIDs>
      <DBID value="102" />
      <DBID value="103" />
      <DBID value="1009" />
      <DBID value="1010" />
      <DBID value="1011" />
      <DBID value="1012" />
      <DBID value="1013" />
      <DBID value="1014" />
      <DBID value="1015" />
      <DBID value="1016" />
      <DBID value="1017" />
      <DBID value="1018" />
      <DBID value="1019" />
      <DBID value="1020" />
    </agentDBIDs>
  </CfgAgentGroup>
</ConfData>
```

I can filter the agentDBIDs/DBID value, but I have no idea how to get its CfgGroup/DBID value. This is what I've done so far:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = AllAgentGroupXML.SelectNodes("/ns:ConfData/ns:CfgAgentGroup/ns:agentDBIDs/ns:DBID", nsMgr); 

foreach (XmlNode abc in nodeList) 
{ 
  if (abc.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString() == "103")
    Console.WriteLine(abc.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString());
}
```

*Note: ns = namespace, nsMgr = XmlNamespaceManager

**Update:**

Use the same XML as above, is there any ways to search the specific agentDBID/DBID value and return its CfgGroup/DBID value? How about using the `where` clause?

**Update2:**
Based on the XML above, how can I get the part of the XML data below if my searching value = 994 (referring to agentDBIDs/DBID value)?

```
<CfgAgentGroup>
   <CfgGroup>
      <DBID value="109" />
         <tenantDBID value="1" />
         <name value="group1" />
         <contractDBID value="0" />
    </CfgGroup>
      <agentDBIDs>
         <DBID value="103" />
         <DBID value="994" />
      </agentDBIDs>
 </CfgAgentGroup>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what's the problem if you use the same way, just different XPath : `/ns:ConfData/ns:CfgAgentGroup/ns:CfgGroup/ns:DBID`

Comment: I don't see any namespace in your XML. You don't need `ns` prefix and `XmlNamespaceManager`.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderPetrov, I need the ns and the nsMgr, if I exclude them, I cannot get any value. The problem is not on them and I used them all over of my coding when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This will  give you the CfgGroup/DBID value(s). Use namespace "System.Xml". In this case I have printed CfgGroup/DBID value if it is 103 (agentDBIDs/DBID value).

```
        string lstr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(PathOfXML);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(lstr);


            XmlNodeList CFG_Group_DB_nodeList = doc.SelectNodes(@"/ConfData/CfgAgentGroup/CfgGroup/DBID");

            foreach (XmlNode n1 in CFG_Group_DB_nodeList)
            {

               if (n1.Attributes["value"].Value == "103")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(n1.Attributes["value"].Value);
                }


            }
```

Comment: Hi @AkshayDubey, thanks for your solution, but there is no result printed out

Comment: @YWah it is because, that in  your XML file  <CfgGroup> does not contain DBID with value ="103". You can check it with other values. For check ,change the code to check for value="109" which is present in your XML.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. My problem now is how can I get CfgGroup/DBID value if my filter value is agentDBIDs/DBID value = 103.